# Swift CoreData subclass not working

Tags: core-data, swift

i know that this has been asked a couple of times but the usual solution does not seem to work for me. I created a CoreData entity and a subclass for it using <ProjectName>.<SubclassName> syntax as class name. Creating a new object like this:

```
let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext) as User
println("-->\(object)<--")

object.setValue(12, forKey: "userID")
object.setValue("username", forKey: "username")
```

the console output:
[image]
although the object does not get printed in the console it seems to have been in some way created and setting a value on that object refers to a Core Data Object

when i use it without a subclass it works as expected (setting Class name back to default):

```
let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext) as NSManagedObject
println("-->\(object)<--")
```

output:
[image]

Here's my subclass declaration:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var userID: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var username: String

}
```

and here's the core data model form:

[image]

What's wrong with the code? Or do i miss anything?

Comment: Show your subclass declaration.

Comment: `let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as NSManagedObject` and `let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as User` always return `"--><--"` when I send a `println("\(object)")` but it doesn't prevent me to add attributes and to save `object` without any crash in a test project... It seems to me that your problem comes from your `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Hey POB, thanks for your reply. mh, when i log the managedObjectContext it outputs "Optional(<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x791e5b70>)" which seems legit. is there anything else i can test it against? the managedObjectContext is derived from the boilerplate  code in AppDelegate when creating a new Project with CoreData enabled

Comment: If you print the expression `CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext` twice, do you get a different pointer each time? It sounds like the managed object context is getting deallocated right after you use it, which indicates that your `CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext` property is returning a new managed object context every time, not the same one.

Comment: @JackLawrence oh crap, that's it, seems like my sharedInstance method is not doing what it ought to do.Logging of CoreDataManager.sharedInstance always printed "CoreDataManager.self" which wasn't all that helpful. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @warly Awesome! I posted the solution as a more fleshed out answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the expression `CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext` twice, do you get a different pointer each time?

It sounds like the managed object context is getting deallocated right after you use it, which indicates that your `CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext` property is returning a new managed object context every time, not the same one, or your `sharedInstance` property is returning a new instance every time.

A managed object's in-memory state is stored as a weak reference to a managed object context. When the context drops out from underneath you (e.g. it's no longer referenced and so is deallocated), your managed object's storage disappears.

A few good indicators that this is happening:

- You haven't saved your managed object context yet but a newly created managed object prints as fault
- You get weird errors when you try to set a property
- You get weird errors when you try to retrieve a property you just set

Answer (score 2):

For printing out the value of an NSManagedObject, do not use:

```
println(...)
```

But rather use:

```
NSLog(...)
```

Please find an example of using NSLog and an NSManagedObject below:

```
/**
* Called when the user clicks on the save button.
*/
@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Reference to our app delegate
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    // Reference MOC
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    // Create instance of put data model and initialize
    var newItem: List = List(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    // Map our properties
    newItem.item = textFieldItemName.text
    newItem.quantity = textFieldQt.text
    newItem.info = textFieldMoreInfo.text

    // Save our context
    var error: NSError? = nil;
    if (context.hasChanges) {
        if (!context.save(&error)) { // save failed
            println("Save Failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            println("Save Succeeded")
        }
    }

    NSLog("newItem: %@", newItem)

    // Navigate back to root ViewController
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

**Note: I do not know the exact reason (bug, or implementation maybe ...) but it turns out that it does not print out a value when we use println(...) function, instead of that it returns an empty String.**

**Consequently I recommend to all of you guys to use NSLog(...) function instead of println(...) when you want to print out the value of an NSManagedObject.**

Answer (score 1):

Include the following at the top of your .swift file

import CoreData

The reason for not working is it doesn't know which library to reference.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try creating it with this method :

```
let entityDescripition = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(“User”, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
let user = User(entity: entityDescripition, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
```

Comment: then definitely there is something wrong with managedObjectContext.check it with this : ` var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedapplication().delegate as AppDelegate' , 'appDelegate.managedObjectContext`